# JavaScript runtime error only on local machine

Tags: javascript, telerik

I am getting the following javascript error but weird thing is it only happen when I run the application through code on my local machine. Code is running fine on servers. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Unhandled exception at line 6, column 74203 in http://localhost/CCSS/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_RadScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=;;System.Web.Extensions,+Version=4.0.0.0,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:en-US:fa6755fd-da1a-49d3-9eb4-1e473e780ecd:ea597d4b:b25378d2;Telerik.Web.UI,+Version=2012.1.215.40,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4:en-US:b29b07e8-2c1e-44e5-9e1b-59bb6459fb01:16e4e7cd:ed16cbdc:f7645509:24ee1bba:f46195d3:2003d0b8:1e771326:aa288e2d:b7778d6c:e085fe68:7165f74:e330518b:c8618e41:8e6f0d33:6a6d718d:7c926187:8674cba1:c08e9f8a:59462f1:a51ee93e:82923ac3:2e42e72a:ef347303:cb4a7569:30f1f089:874f8ea2:19620875:490a9d4e:58366029:bd8f85e4

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'control' of undefined or null reference

Update: This is the line that throws the error
    Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox, {"_dropDownWidth":0,"_height":0,"_skin":"Default","_text":"5","_uniqueId":"ctl00$MainContent$AddressUpdate$grdAddresses$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$PageSizeComboBox","_value":"5","clientStateFieldID":"ctl00_MainContent_AddressUpdate_grdAddresses_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState","collapseAnimation":"{\"duration\":450}","expandAnimation":"{\"duration\":450}","itemData":[{"value":"5","selected":true,"attributes":{"ownerTableViewId":"ctl00_MainContent_AddressUpdate_grdAddresses_ctl00"}},{"value":"10","attributes":{"ownerTableViewId":"ctl00_MainContent_AddressUpdate_grdAddresses_ctl00"}},{"value":"20","attributes":{"ownerTableViewId":"ctl00_MainContent_AddressUpdate_grdAddresses_ctl00"}},{"value":"50","attributes":{"ownerTableViewId":"ctl00_MainContent_AddressUpdate_grdAddresses_ctl00"}}],"localization":"{\"AllItemsCheckedString\":\"All items checked\",\"ItemsCheckedString\":\"items checked\",\"CheckAllString\":\"Check All\"}","selectedIndex":0}, {"selectedIndexChanged":Telerik.Web.UI.Grid.ChangePageSizeComboHandler}, null, $get("ctl00_MainContent_AddressUpdate_grdAddresses_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox"));
});

Comment: That error doesn't mean much to us without the code it's referencing. However, `Unable to set property 'control' of undefined or null reference` means just that -- whatever is trying to set the `control` property isn't defined.

Comment: A browser debugger will let you pinpoint the error down to the line, so I'd crack open Chrome debugger or the like and try running the page, then peering at the error callstack that is generated. Or you can grep your codebase form something like `/\w\.control/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually disabling Visual Studio browserlink resolves that problem - Here's a link showing how to disable it http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: Awsome! It resolve the issue and I am no more getting that error now.